# Is there a way to list the inboxes accessible in the current Outlook session?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to retrieve a list of email inboxes (that is all accessible inboxes, primary, shared and delegated) in an Outlook session. All I need are the String email addresses for these inboxes, so the example code below just prints these out in message boxes (that isn't what will actually happen with them, of course!).

I think I'm just being stupid and can't find the relevant property to loop through?

The following doesn't seem to return inbox for which the session has delegated access:

```
Public Sub PrintAccounts()
    Dim accounts As Outlook.accounts
    Set accounts = Application.Session.accounts
    Dim account As Outlook.account
    For Each account In accounts
        MsgBox account.DisplayName
    Next account
End Sub
```

Many thanks!

NOW ANSWERED:

```
Private Sub DisplayedMailboxesNames()
    Dim colStores As Stores
    Dim oStore As Store
    Set colStores = Session.Stores
    For Each oStore In colStores
        Debug.Print ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(oStore.displayName)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP(displayName As String) As String
    Dim oRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oEU As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oEDL As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
    Set oRecip = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(displayName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    If oRecip.Resolved Then
        Select Case oRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
            Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            Set oEU = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
            If Not (oEU Is Nothing) Then
                ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEU.PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If
            Case OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry
            Set oEDL = oRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
            If Not (oEDL Is Nothing) Then
                ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP = oEDL.PrimarySmtpAddress
            End If
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The usual procedure is to make an answer post, not to edit the answer into the question. When allowed you may accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Accounts are not the same as mailboxes.

Add all accessible mailboxes to the user's GUI then:

```
Private Sub DisplayedMailboxesNames()

    Dim colStores As Stores
    Dim oStore As Store
    Dim oRoot As Folder
    
    Set colStores = Session.Stores
    
    For Each oStore In colStores
        Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder
        Debug.Print oRoot.folderPath
        Debug.Print oRoot.Name
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!

I specifically needed the email address, rather than display names, but having combined this with another Function I've managed to retrieve emails.